# How many complementary partitions are there?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory

> Suppose that we have $m$ objects $O_1,\ldots,O_m$ and a partition $P^*$ dividing them into $n$ blocks (with block sizes $k_1,\ldots,k_n$, $k_i\geq 1$, $\sum_ik_i=m$). How many complementary partitions $P$ to $P^*$ are there?

Complementarity is defined as follows. We can think of any partition as an edge scheme for a graph with nodes $O_1,\ldots,O_m$ divided into cliques within which there is an edge between every 2 nodes; distinct cliques are disconnected. Then, $P$ is complementary to $P^*$ if the edge union of $P$ and $P^*$ constitute a connected graph.

I'll really appreciate either a proof or a pointer to a self-contained reference. Thank you.

Comment: Does $P$ fulfill the same block-size criteria as $P^*$?

Comment: @Joffan Thanks. For your question: no, the only requirement for $P$ is it complements $P^*$ in the sense described in the question.